# Yiimailer CException View not found

Tags: yii, phpmailer, yii-extensions

i have a problem with yii mailer 
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimailer/

I followed the instructions and I put the extension in protected. However it does not work and at the end of the process , it displays an error

http://i61.tinypic.com/2nvulgn.png

here the code i'm using to send email

```php
public function actionCreate() {
                $model = new Tesi;
                $docente = Docente::model();
                $tutti = $docente->findAll();


                        //some code   .....


                    if ($model->save()) {

                        $filetmp = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../upload/' . $fileName;
                        $uploadedFile->saveAs($filetmp);  // image will uplode to rootDirectory/banner/

                        $mail = new YiiMailer();
                        $mail->setView('create');
                        $mail->setAttachment($filetmp);
                        $mail->SetFrom('***myemailhere***', '**'); 
                        $mail->AddAddress($user->mail, $user->name); 
                        $mail->AddAddress($docente->mail, $docente->name); 
                        $mail->Subject = 'Nuova Form Compilato';
                        $body = "<body><h1>E' stata inserito un nuovo item</h1><p>Ti ricordiamo che per la pubblicazione online dovrai attendere</p></body>";
                        $mail->MsgHTML($body);

                        if ($mail->send()) {
                            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('contact', 'Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');

                        } else {
                            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', 'Error while sending email: ' . $mail->getError());
                        }

                    }
                }

                $this->render('create', array(
                    'model' => $model, 'docente_id' => $tutti,
                ));
            }
```

and this one is the function responsible of the error

```
public function setView($view)
{
    if($view!='')
    {
        if(!is_file($this->getViewFile($this->viewPath.'.'.$view)))
            throw new CException('View "'.$view.'" not found');
        $this->view=$view;
    }
}
```

I'm a new user of Yii , so maybe it is possible that i made some mistake.

if you need something more or it is not enough to help me  just leave a comment , i m ready to edit this post and help you to help me .

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is an old one but I came to the same point today and if it helps anybody than its great.
Your problem is that the view you are calling doesn't exist in the folder mailer is looking in. If you go into your config/mail.php file first few lines should describe where the mailer will look for the views and layouts.
For instance:

```
return array(
             'viewPath' => 'application.views.mail',
             'layoutPath' => 'application.views.layouts',
             .....
             );
```

From this point everything is simple. Layout works like normal Yii layout with $content being a variable containing individual views.
So in my case I created a view in the protected/views/mail/ folder and that was it.